# What amount do car rental agencies block on credit cards?

Tags: car-rentals, payment-cards

I'm looking into getting a credit card for use in rental agencies in Europe and the US, which usually block a certain amount on your credit card before rental. However I'm not sure what credit limit I should be asking my bank for?

Do rental agencies usually block the rental amount or a predefined value such as $1000?

Comment: Not sure if that is relevant, but can you define "abroad"? This site is pretty international...

Comment: @DCTLib specified it more

Comment: I'm not sure it's actually answerable as I image each company will have their own policy.

Comment: I'm sure a frequent traveler could give an estimate, e.g. "they usually block $100-$500". That's enough information to have when applying for a credit card.

Comment: @JonathanReez There is no general policy.  The amount may be 0-full price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiring cars in western europe (UK/Spain/France/Switzerland), I've had pre-approved amounts on my card of between nothing and £ (or maybe €)1000. None of these were especially flash cars - I can imagine the place that asked for 1000 off me would seek twice that for a "luxury" vehicle. In the £400-800 range seems to be typical. You could always contact the customer services of the hire car company you intend to use to enquire.

Answer (score 4):

In the US, most car rental companies authorize your card for the full amount of the rental when you pick the car up, plus a bit more (I often see them bump the amount by $100 on week long rentals).

I would look at your intended and potential car rental needs, guessimate your highest possible rental fee and apply for a credit line at least twice that amount.